# Custom Facades in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

> Im a beginner in laravel 5.2 and i was trying to create a custom facades. For that, i have taken a references from the site which is given below

[How to create custom facade in laravel 5.2](http://www.expertphp.in/article/how-to-create-custom-facade-in-laravel-52?utm_source=learninglaravel.net)

I have everything in that references but i got error while routing that class.
My route is:

```
   Route::get('/avatar', function(){
    $img='<img src="'.GeneralClass::getGravatarURL('raimausam32@gmail.com').'">';
    echo $img;   
});
```

But I got error

```
FatalErrorException in routes.php line 15:
```

Class 'GeneralClass' not found

I have no single idea. So please someone help in this problem. It may be simple for others but i am stuck in this problem.

This is my application structure

[image]

```
     Facades/GeneralClass.php

   <?php
    namespace App\Facades;
      use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

    class GeneralClass extends Facade{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'generalclass'; }
    }

      Helpers/GeneralClass.php
        <?php
        namespace App\Helpers;
      class GeneralClass {

        public function getGravatarURL($email, $s = 80, $d = 'mm', $r = 'g', $img = false, $atts = array())
     {
    $url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/';
    $url .= md5(strtolower(trim($email)));
    $url .= "?s=$s&d=$d&r=$r";
    if ($img)
    {
        $url = '<img src="' . $url . '"';
        foreach ($atts as $key => $val)
            $url .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $val . '"';
        $url .= ' />';
      }
     return $url;
     }
     }


    Providers/GeneralClassServiceProvider.php



      <?php

    namespace App\Providers;

     use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

      class GeneralClassServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
/**
 * Bootstrap the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function boot()
 {
    //
  }

/**
 * Register the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function register()
 {
  App::bind('generalclass',function(){
    return new \App\Helpers\GeneralClass;
   });
   }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: did you run `composer dump-autoload` from console? laravel might not realize it was registered because it didn't mentioned in autoload.php.

Comment: of course. i did at last

Comment: well, due to psr-4, make sure the directory exactly like the class namespace. btw, have you checked `vendor\composer\autoload_classmap.php`? did `GeneralClass` mentioned anywhere?

Comment: yes the directory are exactly like the class namespace

Comment: i have included my code here. Help me

Comment: weird, did not see anything wrong.. or just my eye playing with me. just to be sure, check `autoload_classmap.php` if your class did not mentioned there, then something might went wrong. alternatively, you could try to use your facade in controller instead directly in `route.php` so you'll write `use GeneralClass;` explicitly

Comment: If `use GeneralClass;`, like @BagusTesa suggested, didn't work, try `\GeneralClass::getGravatarURL(...`.

Comment: where is autoload_classmap.php?

Comment: in autoload_classmap.php, there is my class                                                     'App\\Facades\\GeneralClass' => $baseDir . '/app/Facades/GeneralClass.php',
    'App\\Helpers\\GeneralClass' => $baseDir . '/app/Helpers/GeneralClass.php',

Comment: your `autoload_classmap.php` looks good, oh well, i'm running out of idea.. does it throw the same error when you used GeneralClass facade in controller?

Comment: yeah. same error..

Comment: *weird*, lets see.. i just checked some old projects of mine (but using laravel 5.3), the way of binding in provider done is a bit different - but it won't hurt to try right? try to change it to looked like [this package](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/blob/master/src/Entrust/EntrustServiceProvider.php#L99) - not mine, but i ever use it as a reference. also, don't forget the `alias` part (i bet this is what's missing). on a side note, you might didn't need to pass anything as you instantiate your `App\Helpers\GeneralClass`

Comment: Bagus Tesa thanks for you time but i am going crazy